# Creating 15x15 matrix out of two 6x6 matrices (by antisymmetrization)

Tags: matrix, tensors

I would like to create the following $15\times 15$ matrix

$A_{ij} = \Lambda^{[I}_{[J} \delta^{M]}_{N]}$

It is tricky because $A$ is a $15\times 15$ whose entries $ij$ are labeled by antisymmetric pair $[IM]$ and $[JN]$ where all indices ($I,J,M,N$) run from 1 to 6, i.e.

$[IM], [JN] ={(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5),(1,6), (2,3), (2,4),..., (4,5),(4,6),(5,6)}$

In other words, $i = [IM]$ and $j=[JN]$.

The $6\times 6$ matrix $\Lambda^I_J$ is defined in **2 steps** as follows:

**Step 1**: Define $M_{IJ}$ and $M2$ (these are $6\times 6$ matrices and there're 15 matrices $M_{IJ}$):

```
M[I_, J_] := Table[KroneckerDelta[I, a] KroneckerDelta[J, b] - 
KroneckerDelta[J, a] KroneckerDelta[I, b], {a, 1, 6}, {b, 1, 6}];
M2 = Sum[M[I,J], {I,1,6}, {J,1,I-1}]
```

so that the form of $M2$ is an $6\times 6$ antisymmetric matrix (with zero diagonal elements and $\pm 1$ off-diagonal elements).

**Step 2**: Define $\Lambda^I_J$ by multiplying the non-zero elements of $M2$ with a parameter (there are 15 nonzero elements so there are 15 parameters):

$\Lambda^I_J$ is defined mathematically (I'm not sure how to define this in Mathematica) by multiplying each of the 15 $\Lambda^I_J$ with a parameter $x_j$, where $j = 1,\,...\,,15$. $\Lambda^I_J$ then should look like this

$\Lambda^I_J =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -x1 & -x2 & -x3 & -x4 & -x5 \\  x1 & 0 & -x6 & -x7 & -x8 & -x9\\ x2 & x6 & 0 & -x10 & -x11 & -x12 \\ x3 & x7 & x10 & 0 & -x13 & -x14 \\ x4 & x8 &x11 & x13 & 0 & -x15 \\ x5&x9&x12& x14& x15& 0 \end{pmatrix} $

Another way to define $\Lambda^I_J$ is to multiply the 15 arbitrary parameters straight with the 15 $M[I,J]$ like this (the result differs by a sign from above - but that doesn't matter)

```
\[CapitalLambda] = x1 M[1, 2] + x2 M[1, 3] + x3 M[1, 4] + x4 M[1, 5] + x5 M[1, 6] + x6 M[2, 3] + x7 M[2, 4] + x8 M[2, 5] + x9 M[2, 6] + x10 M[3, 4] + x11 M[3, 5] + x12 M[3, 6] + x13 M[4, 5] + x14 M[4, 6] + x15 M[5, 6];
```

The $6\times 6$ matrix $\delta^M_N$ is just the KroneckerDelta function.

So the $15\times 15$ matrix $A$ is created from the entries of $\Lambda^I_J$ and $\delta^M_N$. For example:

$A^{12,12} = \Lambda^1_2 \delta^1_2$

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me out with this. Many thanks !

Comment: Your code for $\Lambda^I {}_J$ returns a $6 \times 6$ array for any particular inputs of $I$ and $J$.  Is (for example) $\Lambda^1 {}_2$ supposed to be a $6 \times 6$ matrix?

Comment: Yes, $\Lambda^1_2$ should be an $6\times 6$ matrix with two non-zero entries at positions ($i,j = 1,2$) and $(i,j=2,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

I do not exactly understand what you try to accomplish but maybe the following functions that translate between linear and triangular indexing for properly upper-triangular matrices help?

```
LinearToTriangularIndexing[k_Integer, n_Integer] := Module[{i, j},
   i = n - 1 - Floor[Sqrt[4. n (n - 1) - 8. k + 1.]/2.0 - 0.5];
   j = Subtract[
     k + i + Quotient[Subtract[n + 1, i] Subtract[n, i], 2], 
     Quotient[n (n - 1), 2]];
   {i, j}
   ];

TriangularToLinearIndexing[{i_Integer, j_Integer}, n_Integer] := 
  Subtract[Quotient[n (n - 1), 2] + j, 
   Quotient[Subtract[n + 1, i] Subtract[n, i], 2] + i];
```

For example, we have

```
Table[LinearToTriangularIndexing[i,6], {i,1,Binomial[6,2]}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}}

If you have a general function `f` that turns $[I,M]$ and $[J,N]$ into a number, you can generate your desired matrix with the following (I chose `n = 4` solely in order to make the output printable here):

```
n = 4;
Table[
 IM = LinearToTriangularIndexing[i, n];
 JN = LinearToTriangularIndexing[j, n];
 f @@ Join[IM, JN],
 {i, 1, Binomial[n, 2]}, {j, 1, Binomial[n, 2]}]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 f(1,2,1,2) & f(1,2,1,3) & f(1,2,1,4) & f(1,2,2,3) & f(1,2,2,4) &
   f(1,2,3,4) \\
 f(1,3,1,2) & f(1,3,1,3) & f(1,3,1,4) & f(1,3,2,3) & f(1,3,2,4) &
   f(1,3,3,4) \\
 f(1,4,1,2) & f(1,4,1,3) & f(1,4,1,4) & f(1,4,2,3) & f(1,4,2,4) &
   f(1,4,3,4) \\
 f(2,3,1,2) & f(2,3,1,3) & f(2,3,1,4) & f(2,3,2,3) & f(2,3,2,4) &
   f(2,3,3,4) \\
 f(2,4,1,2) & f(2,4,1,3) & f(2,4,1,4) & f(2,4,2,3) & f(2,4,2,4) &
   f(2,4,3,4) \\
 f(3,4,1,2) & f(3,4,1,3) & f(3,4,1,4) & f(3,4,2,3) & f(3,4,2,4) &
   f(3,4,3,4) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Hello Henrik, thanks for your code ! I am testing it out now. I guess in my case $f$ is the entry of the $15\times 15$ matrix $A$ - I thought I understood it - but apparently after Jose's and Michael's questions above, I got a bit confused about this tensor product between $\Lambda^I_J$ and $\delta^M_N$, but I guess your code should work for any general $f$.

Comment: That's right. I also was confused by your $\lambda$ so I thought that a general method would help you more in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm interpreting correctly the question, but here is what I would do. This is for an arbitrary matrix $\Lambda$.

First, construct the tensor product of the $\Lambda$ matrix and the $\delta$ matrix:

```
Lambda = Array[Λ, {6, 6}];
delta = IdentityMatrix[6];
X = TensorProduct[Lambda, delta];
```

The array `X` has dimensions `{6, 6, 6, 6}`, and if we started with indices `Lambda[I, J]` and `delta[M, N]` then we get `X[I, J, M, N]`. We need to antisymmetrize the pairs `{I, M}` and `{J, N}`, so it is convenient to transpose `X` to have those indices together:

```
Y = Transpose[X, {1, 3, 2, 4}];
```

Now we have `Y[I, M, J, N]`. Antisymmetrize the pairs:

```
Z = Symmetrize[Y, {Antisymmetric[{1, 2}], Antisymmetric[{3, 4}]}];
```

The result is a `SymmetrizedArray` object (a way of storing the result without repeating independent components, or without lots of zeros). If you want the normal array, use `Normal[Z]`.

Then construct the list of 15 antisymmetric pairs you are interested in:

```
comps = SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{6, 6}, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]
(* {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}} *)
```

Finally extract the `{15, 15}` matrix corresponding to those pairs:

```
A = Outer[Extract[Z, Join[##]] &, comps, comps, 1]
```

The result is too large to show here.

I tried to use your definition of `Lambda`, but I do not understand it. That definition produces a matrix per pair `IJ`, while you seem to suggest it should be just a number.

**Edit after the definition of Lambda has been updated:**

Using the new definition of `Lambda`:

```
Lambda = SymmetrizedArray[Thread[comps -> -Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 15]], {6, 6}, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]
```

we have the final result for `A`:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your code with the detailed explanation. I put the code in my ancient Mathematica 8, and currently I got some big error messages which I'm trying to understand - I suspect it's due to the old version. You're right - The entries of the 15 $\times$15 matrix $A$ are defined in terms of the entries of the $\Lambda^I_J$ matrix (not using the entire matrix). For example: $A_{12,34} =\Lambda^1_3 \delta^2_4$.

Comment: This is an "errata" to the last bit in my previous comment "The entries of the 15 $\times$15 matrix $A$ are defined in terms of the entries of the $\Lambda^I_J$ matrix (not using the entire matrix)". At this point, I'm getting a bit confused myself - I know for sure that $A$ are labeled by antisymmetric pair of indices $IM,JN$ and since these run from 1-6, $A$ should be 15D, but I'm confused on the summation part. As written above, clearly $\Lambda^1_3$ should refer to the entire $6\times 6$ matrix labeled as $\Lambda^1_3$, not any particular entry.

Comment: I managed to understand it and edited my definition of $\Lambda^I_J$ in my original question.